# How to make Ajax change a variable on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to implement a like button for a feed using Jquery Ajax.On a feed-page.html.The code works by making a user like or unlike a feed but how can I make `<p id='count'>` reload ajaxly on hitting `Like` button?
Thanks for your help in advance

```
<p>{{feed_detail.text|linebreaks}} </p>
          <p id='count'> {{feed_detail.total_likes}} concern{{feed_detail.total_likes|pluralize:'s'}}</p>
           <p> {{feed_detail.pub_date|naturaltime|capfirst}} </p>
                    <input type="button" id="like" name="{{feed_detail.slug}}" value="Like" />
<script>
$('#like').click(function(){

      $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'like' %}",
               data: {'slug': '{{feed_detail.slug}}' , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
               dataType: "json", 
          }); 
    })
</script>
```

Comment: you should do that in the success block of ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this which is pretty simple

```
<p>{{feed_detail.text|linebreaks}} </p>
          <p id='count'> {{feed_detail.total_likes}} concern{{feed_detail.total_likes|pluralize:'s'}}</p>
           <p> {{feed_detail.pub_date|naturaltime|capfirst}} </p>
                    <input type="button" id="like" name="{{feed_detail.slug}}" value="Like" />
<script>
$('#like').click(function(){

      $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'like' %}",
               data: {'slug': '{{feed_detail.slug}}' , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
               dataType: "json", success: function(){
                       $('#count').load("{% url 'feed_detail' slug=feed_detail.slug %} #count");

                   }
          }); 
    })
</script>
```

This `{% url 'feed_detail' slug=feed_detail.slug %}` should be the url to the current webpage and note the use of `count` id catch to get and reload that part of the page specifically.

Comment: you are doing 2 ajax calls, i suggest you use my code that does only one ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,change the input to type checkbox

```
<p id='count'><span>{{feed_detail.total_likes}}</span> concern{{feed_detail.total_likes|pluralize:'s'}}</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="like" name="{{feed_detail.slug}}" value="Like" />
    $('#like').click(function(){
      var el = $(this);
          $.ajax({

                   type: "POST",
                   url: "{% url 'like' %}",
                   data: {'slug': '{{feed_detail.slug}}' , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                   dataType: "json", 
                   success: function(data){
                      if (el.is(':checked')) {
                       $('#count span').text(parseInt($('#count span').text())+1);
                      } else {
                      $('#count span').text(parseInt($('#count span').text())-1);
                      }
                   }
              }); 
        });
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gxup1wpo/

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt work.What it does is on click of Like.It append 1 to text like for example if there where '2 concerns' before,it does '21' on another click '211' and so on.I want something that will reload the variable {{feed_detail.total_likes}} in #counts on clicking like button.So it is '3 concerns'

Comment: This works except for an issue which is on page visit or reload it doesn't show {{feed_detail.total_likes}} unless Like is checked then it shows.What can  I do about this?

Comment: {{feed_detail.total_likes}}  is from the db so when you reload the page it should output the updated count

Comment: I don't know too.I will try to figure out what is wrong.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for success function.

```
.done(function(response) {
    alert( response );
    console.log( response );
})
```

And check the console log in your browser. Check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info.